# Adding a value to each of digit of a number

Tags: java

I've just started learning about java programming and in one of the exercises given, I've been instructed to do up a java programme that can key in 4 digits and subsequently.

(1) Add 3 to each of the digits and modulus the sum by 10

(2) Swap the 1st and the 3rd digits; the 2nd and the 4th digits

As I'm still very new to this I've only managed to do up a code that's able to enter the numbers and I'm not sure of how to add a value to each digit. However I've been told that arrays are not needed for this as this is just the beginning of the course. This is the code that I have so far. Greatly appreciate any help given.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter 4 digits interger to be encrypted: ");
    int e = input.nextInt();


    System.out.print("Encrypted interger is:" +e);


    System.out.print("Enter 4 digits interger to be decrypted: ");
    int d = input.nextInt();


    System.out.print("decrypted interger is:" +d);
```

Comment: How should you swap them when you don't use an array? Also I don't understand what your written code has to do with your exercise

Answer (score 1):

Rather than posting the actual solution, I'll give you some clues so you get the line of thoughts for getting to it

You already have your 4 digit number with `int e = input.nextInt();`. Having a number of multiple digits, you can extract its units digit by doing a modulus 10

```
number: 1234
1234 % 10 = 4
units: 4
```

Also, once you already have the units, you can "ignore" them by dividing your original number by 10

```
number: 1234
1234 / 10 = 123
number without units: 123
```

By extracting the digits, you'll be able to operate on them independently.

You could as well add some checks to make sure that you have a 4 digit number. Since we're operating with numbers (and not with strings with a `.length()` method) we know that a 4 digit number is a number X so `1000 <= X <= 9999`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation it helped me get a better picture of how to implement it and I managed to solve the exercise! I like programming however as I just started the course it's difficult to grasp the concept of everything

Answer (score 1):

As also the above answers say the only thing you have to do is to seperate the digits and then work on every one alone like:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int e = 0;

    do {
        System.out.print("Enter 4 digits interger to be encrypted: ");
        e = input.nextInt();
    } while (e < 1000 || e > 9999);

    //add 3 and mod by 10 to each digit
    int n1 = ((e / 1000 % 10) + 3) % 10;
    int n2 = ((e / 100 % 10) + 3) % 10;
    int n3 = ((e / 10 % 10) + 3) % 10;
    int n4 = ((e / 1 % 10) + 3) % 10;

    //swap places
    int enc = n3 * 1000 + n4 * 100 + n1 * 10 + n2 * 1;

    System.out.println("Encrypted interger is: " + enc);

    int d = 0;

    do {
        System.out.print("Enter 4 digits interger to be decrypted: ");
        d = input.nextInt();
    } while (d < 1000 || d > 9999);

    //add 10 to be able to subtract 3 and don't get minus
    int d1 = (((d / 1000 % 10) + 10) - 3) % 10;
    int d2 = (((d / 100 % 10) + 10) - 3) % 10;
    int d3 = (((d / 10 % 10) + 10) - 3) % 10;
    int d4 = (((d / 1 % 10) + 10) - 3) % 10;

    //swap places again
    int dec = d3 * 1000 + d4 * 100 + d1 * 10 + d2 * 1;

    System.out.print("decrypted interger is:" + dec);
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort to help me with my question! However would you be able to explain the do loop meaning for it? I tried putting a while (e > 1000 || e < 9999) in my code without the do loop but couldn't seem to get it to not run if 5 or more digits are entered

Comment: The do loop is just checking for a 4 digit integer. If the user enters a 3 or smaller or a 5 or bigger integer the code will run again and ask for a new integer until a 4 digit one is given. You could do that in a lot of ways. I used the simplest one i thought.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the most readable solution is

- check for `e <= 9999` (I assume zeros for e < 1000)
- declare variables for digits: `int d1 = e % 10, d2 = e/10%10, ...`
- compute new digits `int n1 = ...`
- assemble result `int result = 1000 * n2 + 100 * n1 + 10 * n4 + n3` (note swapping)

(just hint, it's your exercise to complete it)